# Extract values from between nested curly brackets

Tags: bash, grep

I'm creating a certain report on F5 loadbalancer and I need to extract the names of the pool member(s) from the pool.
The pools are defined in this manner:

```
gtm pool a dns pool_name{
   value1
   value2
   (...)
   members {
      member1 {
         member-order 0
      }
      member2 {
         member-order 1
      {
      (...)
         membern {
            member-order n
      {
   }
```

Right now I managed to find a pattern with the member naming to grep against, but I can't be sure it is consistent in the whole environment.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your `grep`?  How does it not meet your requirement?  The consistency is impossible to evaluate on our end with just 1 example (and I do not have a fleet of F5 to test that :)

Comment: I grep by a part of a name that is consitent (node_CDC or something like that).
I need something more flexible, that does not realy on any consistency

Comment: So you want to extract the "member1", "member2", "membern" from your example?  And do these names have a pattern or they could be anything.  Because if there is a pattern, grep will be ok, but if not you will need something that understands the structure of the file.

Comment: Follow up, does F5 provide you that extract in json or yaml format (or some other known data file format?).  There are tools to parse those.

Comment: There is REST API to use, but I know nothing on how to use it. I got some basic bash skills apart from my network skills ;)

There is a pattern for this particular device, which I could grep against. What I need is a more versatile solution, as I got some more under my watchful eye. 

Actually you can leave out F5 from it at all and treat the problem as extracting certain strings from  structured pattern.

Comment: Since it is not a format with tags and attributes, you have to parse the structure itself.  You could do **1** make sure there is a `\n` after every `{` to split the results on different lines.  **2** read lines until you reach "members".  **3** the first word is a member, echo it.  Ignore everything after that work (from `{` to `}`).  **4** repeat step 3 until you reach the `}` that closes the "members" section.

Comment: The meber1 member2 etc are own names. But you actually gave me an idea. "member-order" is common after each member definition. I will try grepping B 1 and getting rid of everything else. But not till Monday :)

Comment: Since you are trying to parse what looks like an nftables structure, you might want to contact the members of the Netfilter organization to see if they might already have something that would offer a solution.